# How to redirect after login success to dashboard using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, react-navigation

I have a dashboard, I want when I post my login page, it will be redirected on the dashboard.
My component is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import fav from './favicon.ico';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch,  Link  } from 'react-router-dom';
class Login extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email :"",
      password:""
    }
   this.handleClick =this.handleClick.bind(this);
   // this.handleredirect =this.handleredirect.bind(this);
  }
     handleClick(event){

    var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
        "password":this.state.password
    }
    axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/app/login/',
          data: payload,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        })
   // axios.post('/app/login/', payload)
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
     if(response.data.code == 200){
      <Link to="/dashboard"/>

     }
     else if(response.data.code == 204){
       swal("Erreur !", "Vérifiez vos champs SVP !", "error");
       //alert(response.data.success)
     }
     else{
       swal("Erreur !", "Username inexistant !", "error");
       //alert("Username does not exist");
     }
   })
  }
  handleredirect(){
    this.props.history.push("/register");
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="8">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <Form method="POST" >
                     <div style ={{textAlign:"center"}}> <img src={fav} /></div><br/>

                      <h2 style ={{textAlign:"center"}}>Se connecter</h2><br/>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" autoComplete="username" value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value })} required/>
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="fa fa-lock"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="password" value={this.state.password} placeholder="Password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value })} autoComplete="current-password"   required/>
                      </InputGroup>
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs="6">
                          <Button type="button" color="primary" className="px-4" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>Login</Button>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                          <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <Card className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: 44 + '%' }}>
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div><br/><br/><br/>
                      <h2 style ={{textAlign:"center"}}>S'inscrire</h2><br/>
                      <p>Vous n'avez pas de compte <strong>BRILLO</strong> ? <br/><br/>
                      Créez le !</p>
                      <Button color="primary" className="mt-3" active onClick={() => this.handleredirect()}>Créer compte</Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </CardGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

My routes for pages as login and register :
https://codeshare.io/GboVvO

My routes for dashboard :

https://codeshare.io/5oDeQZ

When I sumbit the login page, I get : CANNOT POST/

How can I run it please ?

Comment: If you're getting "CANNOT POST/" it means, that your request is directed to the `/` instead of desired `/app/login`. That can be, because your not doing `event.preventDefault()` as the first line in your `handleClick(event)` method. So you're posting your `<Form>`, which does not have `action` and in such case it's posting to the current route. So you need to stop this event and fire your `axios()`. Try adding `event.preventDefault();` as the first line in your `handleClick(event)` method

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek it's still the same issue

Comment: Are you sure that your services do not have problems with cors?

Comment: Yes @JackNavaRow, my backend also works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you should remove the method='POST' from your form element because in this case, button acts as a submit button for your form and instead of running your handleClick function which sends the actual request to the server, the form tries to post something which is not defined so it gives the error can not POST.

Then for your redirect to dashboard after login succeeds instead of you  you should write: location.assign('/dashboard'); , this will redirect the user to dashboard after a successful login.

Comment: I get `Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals`

Comment: you can use history object to do the same if you get that warning from location, you should have created the history object with createBrowserHistory module from history library of npm and then import it above your code and after the login succeeds write: history.push('/dashboard')

Comment: after the login succeeds, it redirected to http://localhost:5000/?#/login but I want it to redirects to my dashboard

Comment: Didi you use history.push?

Comment: Yes @Mehrnaz.sa

Comment: Can i see the code in your if statement when the status code is 200 and the login has succeeded?

Comment: `if(response.data.code == 200){
     history.push('/dashboard') 

     }`

Comment: In your handleredirect function , you are redirecting the user to register page using history, does that function work fine?

Comment: Yes @Mehrnaz.sa, it appears because they are on the same routes for pages (App.js)

Comment: @Melissa i think it should be: this.props.history.push('/dashboard') cause i asume you are passing history as a prop and you are using react router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179336/discussion-between-melissa-and-mehrnaz-sa).